# ¿Falta configuraciones para NGinx?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

espero tengan un excelente día, tarde o noche, me he topado con un inconveniente al momento de intentar publicar mi pagina, uso contenedores de Docker, mi pagina esta hecha en Angular5 y uso como servidor Nginx.

Tengo 2 paginas y 2 apis funcionando en el mismo servidor y todo va de maravilla, sin embargo el intentar publicar una nueva pagina al poner la url me lleva a una pagina de Nginx con la siguiente informacion:

**¡Bienvenido a nginx!**

Si ve esta página, el servidor web nginx se ha instalado y funciona correctamente. Se requiere configuración adicional.

Para obtener documentación y soporte en línea, consulte nginx.org .
El soporte comercial está disponible en nginx.com.

*Gracias por usar nginx.*

Este es mi archivo **DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML**

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  refund-mat:
    build:  .
    container_name: refund-mat
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 400M
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=refund.mi.dominio.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=refund.mi.dominio.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@mi.dominio.com


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

y este mi archivo **DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM node:8.6 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/

RUN $(npm bin)/ng build -prod -aot false

FROM nginx:1.13
COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Y tambien tengo esta configuracio de **NGINX-CUSTOM.CONF**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme colegas, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He podido solucionar mi problema, hice 2 cosas:

1) Agregue un archivo adicional a mi proyecto `.dockerignore` que se me había pasado por alto, dentro del archivo solo coloco lo siguiente: `node_modules`.

2) Cree un repositorio en `Docker Hub` para poder obtener la imagen desde el `DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML` y en la version que tenia de `2.1` la cambia a `3`, mi archivo `.yml` finalmente quedó así:

```
version: "3"
services:
  refund:
    image: username/refund
    container_name: refund
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 400M
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=refund.mi.dominio.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=refund.mi.dominio.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@mi.dominio.com


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Una vez subido los cambios a `Git` espero que `Docker Hub` haga la construcción y finalmente ejecuto los comandos `docker-compose pull` y `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Puedes marcar tu pregunta como aceptada, te ganaras dos puntos !

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener el virtual host o poner por defecto un vhost. 
en el caso que presentas no tienes un vhost por defecto o el server_name.

Recuerda que para que este por defecto luego del puerto usas default
Mira la directiva default server y si tienes uno ya lo mejor es crear un server name

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
 location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
 }
}
```

Comment: He podido solucionar mi problemas, no tenia nada que ver con el vhost o server_name, en breve publicare la respuesta.